Is it a proper practice to inject a service provider when I need to get multiple instances of a dependency from within a singleton?
I have a service which has a structure like this:
class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService 
{
    // ...
    Dictionary<int, MyWorker> _workers

    public MyBackgroundService(/*a bunch of injected dependencies*/)
    {
        // store the injected dependencies in private fields
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (_myWatcher.GetNewConfigurations(out var newConfigurations)
            {
                foreach (var newConfiguration in newConfigurations)
                {
                    _workers[newConfiguration.Id] = new MyWorker(/*pass in all the injected private fields*/);
                }
            }

            // some code to remove workers that are no longer needed from the dictionary
           // some code to break out of the loop when appropriate
        }
    }

    // ...
}

Basically, there is an external configuration service that my service polls for new configurations, and upon receiving one, my class spins up a new worker for the new configuration.
MyBackgroundService is a singleton, so there is only ever one instance of it. Since I have several injected dependencies that I currently need to inject into MyBackgroundService that it doesn't actually use for anything, I'm wondering if, instead, I should simply inject the ServiceProvider itself, and call GetService<MyWorker>() in order to instantiate a new instance of the MyWorker class when a new configuration is found, like this:
class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService 
{
    // ...
    Dictionary<int, MyWorker> _workers
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public MyBackgroundService(IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        _serviceProvider = sp;
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (_myWatcher.GetNewConfigurations(out var newConfigurations)
            {
                foreach (var newConfiguration in newConfigurations)
                {
                    _workers[newConfiguration.Id] = _serviceProvider.GetService<MyWorker>();
                }
            }

            // some code to remove workers that are no longer needed from the dictionary
           // some code to break out of the loop when appropriate
        }
    }

    // ...
}

This code is cleaner, because MyBackgroundService doesn't take in a bunch of dependencies that it only needs to instantiate the MyWorkers. But it just seems... wrong to pass the service provider around.
The other obvious option is a factory pattern, in which I inject a MyWorkerFactory into MyBackgroundService, but that sort of just kicks the can down the road, where instead of MyBackgroundService taking in a bunch of dependencies it doesn't use, MyWorkerFactory does instead.
I thought at first simply injecting the MyWorker class as transient would solve the problem, until I realized that Transient instantiates a new instance for every instance that requests one, but since MyBackgroundService is singleton, there would still only be one MyWorker.
What is the proper way to do this?

Can MyBackgroundService take a constructor parameter of Func<MyWorker>?

If you need to create a MyWorker on demand, then what your Background Service really wants is a "MyWorker Factory".
In the days of yore we would create a class called MyWorkerFactory, give it all of the dependencies needed to create a MyWorker and give it a
CreateWorker() method.
But we've come so far in the world of DependencyInjection and you can simplify that entire class into a single delegate which invokes the IServiceProvider like you're suggesting.
At service registration time, register an instance of Func<MyWorker> that looks like so:
services.AddTransient<Func<MyWorker>>(provider => 
  () => provider.GetRequiredService<MyWorker>());

Note: conveniently, the signature of GetRequiredService is Func<MyWorker> so you can simplify that by simply passing the method itself as an argument like so:
services.AddTransient<Func<MyWorker>>(provider =>
  provider.GetRequiredService<MyWorker>);

Then, your background service will take your factory as an injected argument like so:
class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService {
  private readonly Func<MyWorker> _workerFactory;

  public MyBackgroundService(Func<MyWorker> workerFactory){
    _workerFactory = workerFactory;
  }

  protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token){
    // ...
    var newWorker = _workerFactory.Invoke();
    // ...
  }
}

